# How to remove rubric title repeated on several pages (LaTeX, CurVe)

Tags: latex

I am using the package CurVe in Latex for my CV, and in accordance with the documentation: "If a rubric has to be split across different pages, its title will be repeated automatically." How to disable this behaviour, how to not repeat rubric titles ?

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: This seems to remove part of the continuation, but still doesn’t completely solve your problem https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479998/how-can-i-remove-continued-from-2nd-page I am also struggling with this problem.

Comment: hi alpha32 and @Bashima, I have asked a separate question on the Latex channel and this answer solves the problem https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/590708/how-to-disable-repeating-continuation-of-section-header-in-latex-curve-for-cv